# What did I do wrong with this integral problem?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, definite-integrals, solution-verification

> Find the value of the following definite integral
> $$\int_0^{\pi/2} \sqrt{1 - \sqrt{3}\sin 2x + 2\cos^2x} \, dx$$

- My attempt:

$$\int_0^{\pi/2} \sqrt{1 - \sqrt{3}\sin 2x + 2\cos^2x} \, dx$$
$$= \int_0^{\pi/2} \sqrt{2 - \sqrt{3}\sin 2x + \cos2x} \, dx$$
$$= \int_0^{\pi/2} \sqrt{2 + 2\cos \left(2x + \dfrac{\pi}{3}\right)} \, dx$$
$$= \sqrt{2} \int_0^{\pi/2} \sqrt{1 + \cos \left(2x + \dfrac{\pi}{3}\right)} \, dx$$

Let $u = 1 - \cos \left(2x + \dfrac{\pi}{3}\right) \implies du = 2\sin \left(2x + \dfrac{\pi}{3}\right) \, dx = 2\sqrt{2u - u^2} \, dx \implies dx = \dfrac{1}{2\sqrt{2u - u^2}} \, du$

The integral become:

$$\sqrt{2}\int_{1/2}^{3/2} \dfrac{\sqrt{2-u}}{2\sqrt{2u - u^2}} \, du$$
$$= \sqrt{2}\int_{1/2}^{3/2} \dfrac{1}{2\sqrt{u}} \, du$$
$$= \sqrt{2} \cdot \left(\sqrt{u}\right) \Biggr|_{1/2}^{3/2} = \sqrt{3} - 1$$

However, using my calculator and other online calculators, they're all giving $3 - \sqrt{3}$, which is different from mine.

So what did I do wrong?

A small realization I found out is that:

$$\text{(Calculator answer) = $\sqrt{3} \cdot$ (My answer)}$$

Comment: You have switched the - to + form 3rd to 4rth line.......... (and by the way nice math jax!)

Comment: @AlbusDumbledore Oh, it's just my typo. I fixed it. The result is still $\sqrt{3}-1$ (Also thanks for your compliments:) )

Comment: If you have access to a calculator that is able to evaluate integrals (symbolically or numerically), you could always approach this by checking the integral at every step.  The step when the value changes would be where your error is.  Even if you are still confused what the error is, this would allow you to refine your question.

Comment: @AlbusDumbledore I thought that is right. Because:
$$2\cos (2x+\pi/3) = 2 \cdot (\cos 2x \cdot \cos (\pi/3) - \sin 2x \cdot \sin (\pi/3)) = 2 \cdot (1/2 \cos 2x \cdot - \sqrt{3}/2 \sin 2x) = -\sqrt{3} \sin 2x+\cos 2x$$

Comment: @windowsprime sorry ,made an error in calculation

Comment: I believe your issue is that the integrand function is always positive, but somewhere in your substitutions, you lose that, so you're integrating some $f(x)$ rather than $\lvert f(x) \rvert$. Look at the graph: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Integrate%5BSqrt%5B1-Sqrt%5B3%5DSin%5B2x%5D%2B2Cos%5Bx%5D%5E2%5D%2C+%7Bx%2C0%2CPi%2F2%7D%5D

Comment: @BrianMoehring I have used integral-calculator.com. However when I evaluate the answer from the indefinite integral solution it got, it gives $-\sqrt{3}$, but their numerical integral approximation is $3 - \sqrt{3}$

Comment: It is easier if you use $2+2\cos(2x+\frac\pi3)=4\cos^2(x+\frac\pi 6)$ instead of going through the $u$.  So you want $\int_0^{\pi/2}2\lvert\cos(x+\frac\pi6)\rvert\,\mathrm{d}x$ which gives the answer.

Comment: It is not always true that $2\sin \left(2x + \dfrac{\pi}{3}\right)  = 2\sqrt{2u - u^2}$.

Comment: It seems you've made two mistakes.  The more major one is what mathlove mentions, where for $x \in (\pi/3, \pi/2]$, we'd have $2\sin\left(2x+\frac{\pi}{3}\right) = -2\sqrt{2u-u^2}$ and the second, which helped hide the first error, was swapping the limits.

Comment: Ah yes, I have understood my mistakes and found out the way to resolve them. Thank you all for the help :D

Comment: Another way to expand - ${1 - \sqrt{3}\sin 2x + 2\cos^2x} = \sqrt {\sin^2x - 2 \sqrt{3} \sin x \cos x + 3\cos^2x} = |\sin x - \sqrt 3 \cos x|$

Answer (score 2):

$$\int_0^{\pi/2}\sqrt{1-\sqrt{3}\sin(2x)+2\cos^2(x)}dx$$
then as you did we know that:
$$\cos(2x)=2\cos^2(x)-1\Rightarrow 2\cos^2(x)=\cos(2x)+1$$
so we have:
$$\int_0^{\pi/2}\sqrt{2-\sqrt{3}\sin(2x)+\cos(2x)}dx$$
try substituting $u=2x\Rightarrow dx=du/2$ so:
$$\int_0^\pi\sqrt{2-\sqrt{3}\sin(u)+\cos(u)}\frac{du}2$$
now set up
$$\sqrt{3}\sin(u)+\cos(u)=A\cos(u+\alpha)$$
solving gives $2\cos\left(x-\frac\pi3\right)$
now we have:
$$\frac1{\sqrt{2}}\int_0^\pi\sqrt{1-\sin\left(u-\frac\pi3\right)}du$$
letting $v=u-\frac\pi3\Rightarrow dv=du$ we get:
$$\frac1{\sqrt{2}}\int\limits_{-\pi/3}^{2\pi/3}\sqrt{1-\sin v}\,dv$$